# PowerMock class can not be resolved to type

Tags: java, powermock

I download the libs from the PowerMock site, but I can't use the createPartialMock and any other PowerMock methods, because I get :

> **PowerMock can not be resolved to type.**

Check this pic about the problem: 
[image]

Let me know what did I do wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class [PowerMock](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-easymock/1.7.1/org/powermock/api/easymock/PowerMock.html) resides in the package :

```
org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock
```

Make sure, you should add an external library jar of `powermock-easymock-1.7.1.jar` to import this class. The jars could be found [here.](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Downloads)